# Python BeautifulSoup webscraping

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I hope sombody can help me with the next issue

**I would like to get the data in one row this is what i get now in my csv :**

```
9200000083649863,bol.com retourdeals
9200000083649863,"41,75"
9200000083649863,ITidee
9200000083649863,"45,88"
9200000083649863,Bol.com
9200000083649863,"47,99"
```

**What i would like :**

```
9200000083649863,bol.com retourdeals ,41,75
9200000083649863,ITidee, 45,88
9200000083649863,Bol.com 47,99
```

**this is the code**

```
def haalprijs_verkoper(ean, Urll):
    URL = Urll
    ean = ean
    page = requests.get(URL)

    csvfile = open('/home/filoor1/webscrape/book1.csv', 'a')
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    soup = ""
    results = ""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find(id='offers')
    naam = results.find_all("p, strong")
    prijs = results.find_all("span")
    # print(results.prettify())
    counter = 0
    for tag in results.find_all([  'strong' , 'span']):
        # print(tag.text)
        aa = tag.text
        aa = aa.replace("Nieuw", "")
        aa = aa.replace("   ", "")
        aa = aa.replace("\n","")
        aa = aa.replace("''", "aaaaaa")
        aa = aa.strip(' "')
        aa = aa.strip('"')
        if aa != "":
            counter += 0.5
            # print(ean, aa, counter)
            csvwriter.writerow([ean, aa])   
    
haalprijs_verkoper(9200000083649863, 'https://www.bol.com/nl/prijsoverzicht/tp-link-tl-sg1005p-switch/9200000083649863/?filter=all&sort=price&sortOrder=asc')
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe if you focues on the last sentence of `haalprijs_verkoper` you can solve. Currently you are writing two variables on the excel `csvwriter.writerow([ean, aa]) `, you need to modify to i.e. `csvwriter.writerow([ean, aa, str(41), str(75)])`. I couldn't understand how you get 41, 75, therefore you need to set by yourself. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I understand that but can not get the price that belong to that seller, if i add the price it will add all the pricess of all sellers to every seller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example to scrape the data and save the correct CSV:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.bol.com/nl/prijsoverzicht/tp-link-tl-sg1005p-switch/9200000083649863/?filter=all&sort=price&sortOrder=asc'
soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser' )

ean = '9200000083649863'

all_data = []
for s, p in zip(soup.select('p.nosp > strong'),
                soup.select('span.product-prices__currency.product-prices__bol-price')):
    all_data.append([ean, s.get_text(strip=True), p.get_text(strip=True)])

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerows(all_data)
```

Saves this `data.csv`:

```
9200000083649863,bol.com retourdeals,"41,75"
9200000083649863,ITidee,"45,88"
9200000083649863,Bol.com,"47,99"
9200000083649863,4Allshop,"49,70"
9200000083649863,codima,"51,69"
9200000083649863,PlazaSale.nl,"53,40"
9200000083649863,Stock Sellers B.V.,"53,67"
9200000083649863,Art & Craft,"54,27"
9200000083649863,ORM Wholesale,"54,38"
9200000083649863,DutchDo B.V.,"55,92"
```